# Implementing bootstrap-datepicker in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am starting with AngularJs.

I need to implement "N" Calendars in a form. I am using bootstrap-datepicker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

It is working fine if I specify the inputTextId for example

Html:

```
<input id='datetimepicker2' data-ng-model="vm.search.origin.from" data-ng-click="vm.showCalendar(this)" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="MM/DD HH:MM">

<input data-ng-model="vm.search.origin.to" data-ng-click="vm.showCalendar(this)" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="MM/DD HH:MM">
```

Controller:

```
function showCalendar(obj)
{
    $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker();
}
```

It works fine for one inputText, and if I want to implement it in more than one I have to specify every name and function. I want to pass the reference and use:

reference.datepicker(); or something like that in order to create just one function.
Is that possible?

Comment: Use: [**angular-ui#datepicker**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Comment: why r u using jquery  $("#datetimepicker2"). in angular Project , its not a good Practice , u have to use angular directives ,ref http://jsfiddle.net/cletourneau/kGGCZ/  or http://plnkr.co/edit/KsK5F1M2zrv0SDTwRM4N?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a directive. Take this as an example:

```
app.directive('timePicker', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
          $(elem).datetimepicker();
        }
    }
});
```

You would then just add `time-picker` to the inputs you want.